# How to call switch function from SSH console using PHP

Tags: php, ssh, console

please, how is possible to get arguments from terminal in php?

Example: *php index.php create*

I can´t assign value "create" from terminal to $action variable.
Here is my code:

```
$action;

switch ($action) {
    case "create":
        echo "create\n";
        break;
    case "delete":
        echo "test1\n";
        break;
    case "test":
        echo "test\n";
        break;
    default:
        echo "default\n";
}
```

Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$action = $argv [1];
```

Before that you should check if it exists:

```
if ($argc < 2)
{
    echo "Usage: $argv[0] action\n";
    exit ();
}
```

This works when you call your program from the command line as

```
php index.php create
```

where `create` is the string you want to pass to the program.